# I couldn't able to locate a button because of pseudo elements

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSRYb.png) How to locate this process button?

My code is shown below:

```
WebElement e= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#credit-manual-process"));
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", e);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
```

I also tried with XPath and id.

Comment: what error did it throw ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Answer (score 0):

looks like this is in iframe, in that case you would need to switch over to iframe in order to access element inside the frame :

**Code to switch**  :

```
driver.switchTo().frame(name_or_id)
```

in place of `name_or_id` - You would have to give, iframe name or id.

and then you can continue :

```
WebElement e= driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#credit-manual-process"));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", e);
```